# How to use React components in Qwik?

Tags: reactjs, qwik

Is it possible to use React components from a component library in Qwik framework?

I'm trying to use components from a dependency that i have installed but they are written in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you can but **should avoid it if you can** and only should use it as a migration strategy. For more information: [Use qwikify$() as a migration strategy](https://qwik.builder.io/integrations/integration/react/#use-qwikify-as-a-migration-strategy)

QwikReact allows you to use React components in Qwik, including the whole ecosystem of component libraries.

You need to install:

```
npm run qwik add react
```

The *qwikify* the component you want to use:

```
/** @jsxImportSource react */

import { qwikify$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-react';
import { ReactComponent } from '@react/component/library';

export const Component = qwikify$(ReactComponent);
```

> Important: You need to import /** @jsxImportSource react */ at the top
> of your file, this is an instruction to the compiler to use React as
> the JSX factory.

For more information see [Qwik React](https://qwik.builder.io/integrations/integration/react/).